# Is there a way to look up only different values in the existing table and in the change history table in the Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using A table and A_Hist table.

The columns in table A are id(PK), a, b, c, d ...

The columns in table A_Hist are id, timestamp, a, b, c, d ...

Table A_Hist uses (id, timestamp) as PK

Both tables are the same except for the timestamp column.

Is there a way to look up only different values for each column in the data of the two tables?

Comment: It's hard to answer the question as it's currently written. Please, update it and add some sample data for all involved tables, desired result and rules to calculate such result for that sample data

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issue/errors with your solution; and the expected output. At the moment the question is not clear what you are trying to compare. Do you want to compare the last row in the history table for each id against the row in the current table so you are only considering the most recent value or do you want to compare all rows of the history table against the source for each id?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't interested in timestamp (as you can't compare it anyway; it doesn't exist in A), then you could

```
select id, a, b, c, d from a
minus
select id, a, b, c, d from a_hist
```

which would return all rows in A that don't exist in A_HIST. Apply the opposite, if needed.

---

Or, you could join tables on ID column and search for differences:

```
select a.id, a.a, b.a,
             a.b, b.b,
             a.c, b.c
             a.d, b.d
from a join a_hist b on a.id = b.id
where a.a <> b.a
   or a.b <> b.b
   or a.c <> b.c
   or a.d <> b.d
```

If NULLs are allowed, use the NVL function, e.g. `where nvl(a.a, 'x') <> nvl(b.a, 'x')`.

Comment: i think it will be difficult to join because there are many columns.
I didn't know the minus keyowrd

thank you :)